# Facebook "like" does not appear in Internet Explorer and Firefox

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

Sometimes Facebook "like" button rendered with 0px of height and weight. This only happens in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but in Chrome it's working and rendered perfectly.

Why does this happen? Any specific reason?

I am using XFBML version without any custom css styles.
I am using xslt file to render it

```
<ul class="gateway-share">
  <li>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;fb:like href="</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$FacebookLikeUrl"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="73"&gt;&lt;/fb:like&gt;</xsl:text>
  </li>

  <li>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;fb:send href="</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$shareUrlWithDomain"/>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">"&gt;&lt;/fb:send&gt;</xsl:text>
  </li>

  <li>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$shareUrlWithDomain"/>"<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&gt;Tweet&lt;/a&gt;</xsl:text>
  </li>

  <li onclick="PinTracking();" title="Send to Pinterest">
    <a id="lnkpinterest" href="{$PinterestShareUrl}" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none">
      <img border="0" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png"/>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

/* css styles for the list */
ul.gateway-share {
  float: left;
  height: auto;
  list-style: none outside none;
  margin: 0 6px 0 10px;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
ul.gateway-share li {
  border: 0 none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see the rendring html tags or classes in which your like button is placed

and give them 
`min-height` and `min-width`

Comment: i tried to fix this issue by using these styles but this make the other buttons in the list frozen 

li.gws-fb-like .fb_edge_widget_with_comment span,
li.gws-fb-like .fb_edge_widget_with_comment span iframe.fb_ltr {
 height: 20px !important;
 width: 73px !important; 
}

li.gws-fb-like .fb_edge_widget_with_comment span iframe.fb_iframe_widget_lift {
 height: 500px !important;
 width: 450px !important; 
}